# Is there a way to set a validation on multiple inputs with similar name? Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to set a validation on multiple inputs with similar name? For ex -

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'zone1' => 'required|numeric',
        'zone2' => 'required|numeric',
        'zone3' => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

Can I do something like `'zone*' => 'required|numeric'`

Comment: I don't think so, but if you can pass `zones` as an array, like `name="zones[]"`, then you can validate like `"zones" => "required|array"`, and `"zones.*" => "numeric"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asterisk as a wildcard but it may not be a great idea. With a rule like `'zone*' => 'required|numeric'` as long as there's a single value that matches the condition the request will pass validation. For example, if a request has a valid value for `zone2` but `zone1` and `zone3` are missing or non-numeric the validation will still pass